# Jquery stops submitting user form values when list is long

Tags: drupal, jquery

I am hoping this is my script and not a Jquery bug (version 1.4.4).This script works fine on the first rows of several tables. The values placed and posted by jquery or user input are correct. But at the end of the table list the form starts submitting incorrectly (checked with firebug). What happens is the values are being posted for the previous entries and not the actual text that is input by the user. Ex the tables for the 2012-10-4 work fine but then those for 2012-09-13 post incorrectly:

jquery:

```
    (function ($) {     

  Drupal.behaviors.mvc = {
    attach: function(context, settings) {      
     $(document).ready(function() {

        // container start

            $('#timetracker-mytime-').ajaxForm({
            success: function(result){

                    var d = new Date();

                    var month = d.getMonth()+1;
                    var day = d.getDate();

                    var output = d.getFullYear() + '-' +
                        ((''+month).length<2 ? '0' : '') + month + '-' +
                        ((''+day).length<2 ? '0' : '') + day;

                    var section = result.split('}{');

                    // show any previously hidden tables
                    //$('#table-').show();
                    $("div:hidden[id*='table-']").show();

                    // hide the working table 
                    // $('#table-' + section[0]).hide();
                    $('div#most-recent-events table > tbody').prepend(section[1]);

                    // remove the last row to keep the list short ( 5 rows )
                    $('div#most-recent-events table > tbody > tr:last').remove();


                    $('div#table-' + section[0] + ' table > thead').append(section[1]);



                    // show new working table
                    /*$('#output').html(section[1]).css({
                            backgroundColor: '#99FF66',
                            padding: '10px'
                            });*/
;
                }

            });

            $('#timetracker-myreports-').ajaxForm({
            target:'#output',
            success: function(){
                            $('#export-form').show();
                            $("#my-report-id").val($('#edit-my-projects-id option:selected').val());
                        }
            });

            $('#update-mini-form').ajaxForm({
            target: this});

            $( "#edit-event-date" ).AnyTime_picker(
                  { format: "%Y-%m-%d",
                    formatUtcOffset: "%: (%@)",
                    placement: "popup" });


            $("a.delete-time").live("click", function(event) {

                event.preventDefault(); 
                var row = $(this).attr("id").split('-');
                var delurl = $(this).attr("href");

                $.ajax({
                        type: "GET",
                        url: delurl,
                        dataType: "html",
                        cache: false,
                        success: function(result){
                            $("#row-" + row[1]).remove();
                            $('#total-user-hours').html(result);
                        }
                });

                return false;

            });

            $("a.update-time").live("click", function(event) {

                event.preventDefault(); 
                var row = $(this).attr("id").split('-');


                $("tr:visible[class*='temp-form']").hide();

                $('#row-' + row[1]).after(
                    $("#mini-form-row").addClass('temp-form').show('slow')

                    );              

                $("#update-entry").show(); 

                // fill in form values

                $("#update-entry #id-mini-form").val($("tr#row-" + row[1] + " td.cell-1-" + row[1]).text());

                $("#update-entry #edit-task").val($("tr#row-" + row[1] + " td.cell-2-" + row[1]).text());

                $("#update-entry #edit-hours").val($("tr#row-" + row[1] + " td.cell-5-" + row[1]).text());

                $("#projects option[value=" + $('#row-' + row[1] + ' > td > #my-projects-id').val() +"]").attr("selected","selected");




            });

            $("div.form-close").live("click", function(event) {
                    $("tr:visible[id*='mini-form-']").hide();
            });

            $("#sendUpdate").live("click",function() {          
                $.ajax({
                            type: "POST",
                            url: "http://drupal.se/timetracker/timetracker/update_time/",
                            data: $('#update-entry').serialize(),
                            cache: false,
                            success: function(result){

                                section = result.split('}{');
                                $('#row-' + section[0]).replaceWith(section[1]);

                            }
                });


                return false;           

            });

            $('#edit-export').live("click", function(){

                    $('#timetracker-myreports-csv-').attr("action", 'http://drupal.se/timetracker/timetracker/myreport_csv/');

                    $('#timetracker-myreports-csv-').submit();

            });


          // container end
      });
    }
  };

})(jQuery);


    <div id="table-2012-10-03"><div class="table-label"><span     class="date">2012-10-03</span><span class="hours"></span></div><table class="sticky-enabled">
 <thead><tr><th>ID</th><th>Task</th><th>Project</th><th></th><th>Hours</th><th colspan="2">Operations</th> </tr></thead>
<tbody>
 <tr id="row-213" class="odd"><td class="cell-1-213">213</td><td class="cell-2-213">the last try before</td><td class="cell-3-213">how beans</td><td><input type="hidden" name="my_projects_id" id="my-projects-id" value="204"></td><td class="cell-5-213">2</td><td class="cell-6-213"><a href="/timetracker/timetracker/delete_time/213/204" class="delete-time" id="del-213">delete</a></td><td class="cell-7-213"><a href="/timetracker/timetracker/update_time/213" class="update-time" id="upd-213">update</a></td> </tr>
 <tr id="row-212" class="even"><td class="cell-1-212">212</td><td class="cell-2-212">dd more because our english has gotten terrible</td><td class="cell-3-212">how beans</td><td><input type="hidden" name="my_projects_id" id="my-projects-id" value="204"></td><td class="cell-5-212">2</td><td class="cell-6-212"><a href="/timetracker/timetracker/delete_time/212/204" class="delete-time" id="del-212">delete</a></td><td class="cell-7-212"><a href="/timetracker/timetracker/update_time/212" class="update-time" id="upd-212">update</a></td> </tr>
 <tr id="row-211" class="odd"><td class="cell-1-211">211</td><td class="cell-2-211">discovering clean fuel sources</td><td class="cell-3-211">how beans</td><td><input type="hidden" name="my_projects_id" id="my-projects-id" value="204"></td><td class="cell-5-211">2</td><td class="cell-6-211"><a href="/timetracker/timetracker/delete_time/211/204" class="delete-time" id="del-211">delete</a></td><td class="cell-7-211"><a href="/timetracker/timetracker/update_time/211" class="update-time" id="upd-211">update</a></td> </tr>
 <tr id="row-209" class="even"><td class="cell-1-209">209</td><td class="cell-2-209">riding the rainbow</td><td class="cell-3-209">project nine</td><td><input type="hidden" name="my_projects_id" id="my-projects-id" value="196"></td><td class="cell-5-209">2</td><td class="cell-6-209"><a href="/timetracker/timetracker/delete_time/209/196" class="delete-time" id="del-209">delete</a></td><td class="cell-7-209"><a href="/timetracker/timetracker/update_time/209" class="update-time" id="upd-209">update</a></td> </tr>
 <tr id="row-206" class="odd"><td class="cell-1-206">206</td><td class="cell-2-206">a game of bones</td><td class="cell-3-206">project ten</td><td><input type="hidden" name="my_projects_id" id="my-projects-id" value="197"></td><td class="cell-5-206">2</td><td class="cell-6-206"><a href="/timetracker/timetracker/delete_time/206/197" class="delete-time" id="del-206">delete</a></td><td class="cell-7-206"><a href="/timetracker/timetracker/update_time/206" class="update-time" id="upd-206">update</a></td> </tr>
 <tr id="row-205" class="even"><td class="cell-1-205">205</td><td class="cell-2-205">a game of thrones</td><td class="cell-3-205">project ten</td><td><input type="hidden" name="my_projects_id" id="my-projects-id" value="197"></td><td class="cell-5-205">2</td><td class="cell-6-205"><a href="/timetracker/timetracker/delete_time/205/197" class="delete-time" id="del-205">delete</a></td><td class="cell-7-205"><a href="/timetracker/timetracker/update_time/205" class="update-time" id="upd-205">update</a></td> </tr>
 <tr id="row-203" class="odd"><td class="cell-1-203">203</td><td class="cell-2-203">trial and lots of errors</td><td class="cell-3-203">project two</td><td><input type="hidden" name="my_projects_id" id="my-projects-id" value="181"></td><td class="cell-5-203">4</td><td class="cell-6-203"><a href="/timetracker/timetracker/delete_time/203/181" class="delete-time" id="del-203">delete</a></td><td class="cell-7-203"><a href="/timetracker/timetracker/update_time/203" class="update-time" id="upd-203">update</a></td> </tr>
 <tr id="row-192" class="even"><td class="cell-1-192">192</td><td class="cell-2-192">driving to philly to get cream cheese</td><td class="cell-3-192">project three to one</td><td><input type="hidden" name="my_projects_id" id="my-projects-id" value="182"></td><td class="cell-5-192">1</td><td class="cell-6-192"><a href="/timetracker/timetracker/delete_time/192/182" class="delete-time" id="del-192">delete</a></td><td class="cell-7-192"><a href="/timetracker/timetracker/update_time/192" class="update-time" id="upd-192">update</a></td> </tr>
 <tr class="odd"><td></td><td></td><td></td><td>Total Hours:</td><td colspan="3" id="total-user-hours">17</td> </tr>
 <tr id="mini-form-row" style="display:none" class="even"><td colspan="7"><div style="text-align:right;cursor:pointer;" class="form-close">close x</div><form method="post" style="display:none" id="update-entry" action="http://drupal.se/timetracker/timetracker/update_time"><table><tr><td><label>Task<input type="textfield" id="edit-task" name="task" value="" size="12"></label></td><td><label>Projects<select id="projects" name="projects"><option selected="selected" value="none"></option><option value="204">how beans</option><option value="217">New project</option><option value="199">project 12</option><option value="206">project 14</option><option value="195">project eight</option><option value="202">project eleven</option><option value="203">project eleven</option><option value="205">project eleven</option><option value="187">project five and five</option><option value="186">project four and seven</option><option value="196">project nine</option><option value="180">project one</option><option value="209">project one</option><option value="210">project one</option><option value="211">project one</option><option value="212">project one</option><option value="213">project one</option><option value="214">Project One</option><option value="215">Project One</option><option value="193">project six</option><option value="197">project ten</option><option value="182">project three to one</option><option value="181">project two</option></select></label></td><td><input type="hidden" name="id_mini_form" id="id-mini-form" value="place"></td><td><label>Hours<input type="textfield" id="edit-hours" name="hours" size="2" value=""></label><td><input type="button" id="sendUpdate" value="update"></td></tr></table></form></td> </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>

    <div id="table-2012-09-19"><div class="table-label"><span class="date">2012-09-19</span><span class="hours"></span></div><table class="sticky-enabled">
 <thead><tr><th>ID</th><th>Task</th><th>Project</th><th></th><th>Hours</th><th colspan="2">Operations</th> </tr></thead>
<tbody>
 <tr id="row-214" class="odd"><td class="cell-1-214">214</td><td class="cell-2-214">hullo world</td><td class="cell-3-214">project nine</td><td><input type="hidden" name="my_projects_id" id="my-projects-id" value="196"></td><td class="cell-5-214">4</td><td class="cell-6-214"><a href="/timetracker/timetracker/delete_time/214/196" class="delete-time" id="del-214">delete</a></td><td class="cell-7-214"><a href="/timetracker/timetracker/update_time/214" class="update-time" id="upd-214">update</a></td> </tr>
 <tr class="even"><td></td><td></td><td></td><td>Total Hours:</td><td colspan="3" id="total-user-hours">4</td> </tr>
 <tr id="mini-form-row" style="display:none" class="odd"><td colspan="7"><div style="text-align:right;cursor:pointer;" class="form-close">close x</div><form method="post" style="display:none" id="update-entry" action="http://drupal.se/timetracker/timetracker/update_time"><table><tr><td><label>Task<input type="textfield" id="edit-task" name="task" value="" size="12"></label></td><td><label>Projects<select id="projects" name="projects"><option selected="selected" value="none"></option><option value="204">how beans</option><option value="217">New project</option><option value="199">project 12</option><option value="206">project 14</option><option value="195">project eight</option><option value="202">project eleven</option><option value="203">project eleven</option><option value="205">project eleven</option><option value="187">project five and five</option><option value="186">project four and seven</option><option value="196">project nine</option><option value="180">project one</option><option value="209">project one</option><option value="210">project one</option><option value="211">project one</option><option value="212">project one</option><option value="213">project one</option><option value="214">Project One</option><option value="215">Project One</option><option value="193">project six</option><option value="197">project ten</option><option value="182">project three to one</option><option value="181">project two</option></select></label></td><td><input type="hidden" name="id_mini_form" id="id-mini-form" value="place"></td><td><label>Hours<input type="textfield" id="edit-hours" name="hours" size="2" value=""></label><td><input type="button" id="sendUpdate" value="update"></td></tr></table></form></td> </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</div><div id="table-2012-09-13"><div class="table-label"><span class="date">2012-09-13</span><span class="hours"></span></div><table class="sticky-enabled">
 <thead><tr><th>ID</th><th>Task</th><th>Project</th><th></th><th>Hours</th><th colspan="2">Operations</th> </tr></thead>
<tbody>
 <tr id="row-215" class="odd"><td class="cell-1-215">215</td><td class="cell-2-215">hullo world two</td><td class="cell-3-215">project one</td><td><input type="hidden" name="my_projects_id" id="my-projects-id" value="180"></td><td class="cell-5-215">4</td><td class="cell-6-215"><a href="/timetracker/timetracker/delete_time/215/180" class="delete-time" id="del-215">delete</a></td><td class="cell-7-215"><a href="/timetracker/timetracker/update_time/215" class="update-time" id="upd-215">update</a></td> </tr>
 <tr class="even"><td></td><td></td><td></td><td>Total Hours:</td><td colspan="3" id="total-user-hours">4</td> </tr>
 <tr id="mini-form-row" style="display:none" class="odd"><td colspan="7"><div style="text-align:right;cursor:pointer;" class="form-close">close x</div><form method="post" style="display:none" id="update-entry" action="http://drupal.se/timetracker/timetracker/update_time"><table><tr><td><label>Task<input type="textfield" id="edit-task" name="task" value="" size="12"></label></td><td><label>Projects<select id="projects" name="projects"><option selected="selected" value="none"></option><option value="204">how beans</option><option value="217">New project</option><option value="199">project 12</option><option value="206">project 14</option><option value="195">project eight</option><option value="202">project eleven</option><option value="203">project eleven</option><option value="205">project eleven</option><option value="187">project five and five</option><option value="186">project four and seven</option><option value="196">project nine</option><option value="180">project one</option><option value="209">project one</option><option value="210">project one</option><option value="211">project one</option><option value="212">project one</option><option value="213">project one</option><option value="214">Project One</option><option value="215">Project One</option><option value="193">project six</option><option value="197">project ten</option><option value="182">project three to one</option><option value="181">project two</option></select></label></td><td><input type="hidden" name="id_mini_form" id="id-mini-form" value="place"></td><td><label>Hours<input type="textfield" id="edit-hours" name="hours" size="2" value=""></label><td><input type="button" id="sendUpdate" value="update"></td></tr></table></form></td> </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

Comment: BTW, the behavior on this is very erratic so if anyone wants to see it happening live I can provide a log in to a live url

Comment: Ok, after check this with some code changes it seems that the form is posting values cached by the browser. Similar to the way a form is filled with previous values on history back. When the values are empty the first time and sent then those values are cached somewhere and sent when the form is posted again. I get the gut feeling this is because I took the suggestion of using a single form and moving it around rather than giving each row it's own form

Comment: Ok, I solved this by going back to my orginal idea of making a form for each row. This also simplified the code a lot. I will leave this unanswered though unless someone comes up with a better solution.

Comment: hmm, that was short. Now even though each table has a seperate form and each form has unique id selectors. Only some of the forms post the correct values while other's gather information from something in the browser session

Comment: Solved again. I was doing some early binding to forms ( in the first table ) with identical id selectors thinking they were not influencing the ajax because I was doing explicit calls to other selectors